# How to iterate over columns in html table

Tags: html, html-table, iteration

I need to iterate over all the rows of the column and move to next column and iterate over all the rows again.I need to iterate vertically using HTML table.Is there a way to do that

Comment: You can use `jQuery` for that.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried checking for `<tr></tr>` in your `<table></table>`?